# How to use WindowGenerator to train a time-series model with multple inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, time-series

I'm new to Keras and still learning about machine learning. I'm currently following the [Tensorflow's time series forecasting tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing). The model is something like and idk if something is wrong with it:

```
first = Sequential([
  LSTM(128, return_sequences=True),  # 1 for load values
  Dropout(0.2),
  Flatten()
])

second = Sequential([
  Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  Dropout(0.2),
  Flatten()
])

combined = Concatenate([first, second])

result = Sequential([
  combined,
  Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  Dropout(0.2),
  Dense(1, 'linear')
])
```

Based on the tensorflow page, the way you train the model is:

```
model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=window.val,
                      callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

How can I achieve this? I tried passing an array `model.fit([window.train, window2.train] ...` but it would throw this:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.map_op._MapDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```